# Problem with polish figure captions in Rnw

Tags: captions, languages

Can anybody help me with figure caption in Rnw?
I think the problem is with encoding.
`<<wDensityGamma2,fig.keep= TRUE, echo=TRUE, fig.cap="Wykresy gęstości rozkładów gamma">>=`

```
curve(dgamma(x,1/2,1),col='red',add=T)
legend("topright", c("G(2,2)","G(1/2,1)"), col=c("blue","red"),
       lwd=2, cex=.85 )
@
```

All packages are here:

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT4]{polski}
```

Outside chunk everything is ok, only the problem is in caption (polish special characters don't work).
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: No sure how Knitr (are you using Knitr?) operates, but maybe the encoding of the caption is different from the encoding declared to `inputenc`. Can you check (in a copy of your document) if switching to UTF-8 everywhere helps (you need to change the `inputenc` line to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` **and** re-encode your document into UTF-8)